# UPX packed binary getting corrupted in MAC

Tags: macos, arm64, macos-big-sur, packer, upx

I am trying to pack a binary with UPX packer in MAC. But the file is getting corrupted in Mac Intel and ARM. I tried UPX in two ways: by installing UXP 4.1.0 through homebrew and by building the master branch from Git. Both are not working.

I'm getting the error "main executable failed strict validation" during code sign or "offset to architecture arm64 extends past end of file".

I tried building UPX code from different branches. All are failing for me. Is there any solution to resolve this issue? UPX is compatible with MAC Intel/ARM64?